# What to do when I'm done multi-threading

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm writing a program in Ruby/Tk.  At one point, I'm performing a task that takes some time and I want to show some feedback.  I've done this with threads.  I'm new to this whole threading thing and don't know how to go back to the non-thread world when I'm done with the threads.

Let me illustrate with an example.

```
legitCreds = true
doneValidate = false

# (A) Thread with time-consuming call
validator = Thread.new do
    # THIS CALL TAKES 5-10 seconds
    legitCreds = checkDoorsCreds(session, ValidateTimeout)

    # indicate when this call is done
    mutex.synchronize do
        doneValidate = true
    end
end

# (B) Thread with GUI feedback for user
timeElapsed = 0
textVisible = false
progress = Thread.new do
    if ! doneValidate
        loop do
            sleep 0.5
            timeElapsed += 0.5

            mutex.synchronize do
                if ValidateTimeout - timeElapsed <= 0 || doneValidate
                    @SI['statMessL'].text = ""
                    Thread.kill(progress)
                end
            end

            if textVisible
                @SI['statMessL'].text = ""
                textVisible = false
            else

                @SI['statMessL'].text = "Timeout in #{(ValidateTimeout - timeElapsed).round} seconds..."
                textVisible = true
            end

        end
    end
end


# (C) Should only run after A and B are done.
if legitCreds
    File.open(PathToUserNames, 'w') { |file| file.write(@SI['unameTB'].get) }
    # Go to next state!
end
```

So the problem is that, as it is coded above, (C) runs before (A) and (B) are done, which is useless because *legitCreds* is set by thread A.

I thought of putting the following code before (C)

```
validator.join
progress.join
```

But this freezes the GUI, which I don't want either.

I also thought of putting the contents of (C) at the end of (A) (but still inside the *validator* thread.  That get me the right behaviour, but it seems wrong because then the rest of my program looks like it will run in the *validator* thread.

To sum up, I want to run (C) after (A) and (B) without freezing the GUI while (A) and (B) are working.

How am I do to that?

Also, if you see any other no-nos, please let me know.  As I said, I'm new to threading and I want to be making good habits.

Thanks,

Grasswistle

Comment: What GUI are you using?

Comment: I mentioned Tk.  If you're looking for something else, could you give me some options to choose from?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I also thought of putting the contents of (C) at the end of (A) (but
>   still inside the validator thread. That get me the right behaviour,
>   but it seems wrong because then the rest of my program looks like it
>   will run in the validator thread.

I'm not familiar with Tk specifically, but from what I know about GUI application, there is no risk that your program will start working from another thread - (C) will simply change the state of the application, and GUI events will continue to be processed from the GUI thread...

So (C) can be appended to either (A) or (B) (seperation of concerns might favor (B) over (A)), and you application should continue smoothly...

Comment: Some behaviour is different from then on in the program though.  Since the rest of the program is running in thread (A) or (B), exceptions no longer halt the program because they are being raised in a thread.  This doesn't seem desirable...

Comment: What exactly does (C) do?

Comment: Mainly, (C) just decides whether the program moves on to the next state or not.  If the program is to move on, (C) will call a function (not shown; sorry) that pushes the program into the next state.

Comment: What if you actively `kill` the thread after (C) finishes its work?